# in C# GetDetailsOf method does not returns actual value, but return2 item Name

Tags: c#, shell

Following my code in C# performs without error, however it returns just "Artist(=int 13)" instead of the actual values.
I would like to know how to correct this issue.

```
 public string getFileDetails(string fileFolder, string filePath, int infotype)
 {
     string strReturnval =null;
     try
     {
         
         var shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
         dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
         Shell32.Folder objFolder = shell.NameSpace(fileFolder);
         Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = objFolder.ParseName(filePath);
         strReturnval = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, infotype);
        
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);         
     }
     finally
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"strReturnval is {strReturnval}");         
     }
     return strReturnval;
 }
```

Though I searched the various web page by Google and Edge, no good example found. I would like to now how to correct my code.

Comment: Which [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof) are you passing as `infotype`? What are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof did you come across this one when you search?